# Adobe Flash - Convert tweened drawing object to symbol

Tags: flash, adobe-flash, animation

I have a drawing object that has a shape tween animation on the timeline (with several keyframes).

Is it possible to convert this drawing object to a movie clip symbol without loosing the keyframes and tween? Kinda "swap" the instance of the drawing object for the movie clip...?